# Simple kernel won't boot in GRUB

Tags: assembly, kernel, qemu, osdev, grub

I'm learning a bit of OS development from [OSDev.org](http://osdev.org). I have a kernel and I'm trying to boot in GRUB Legacy (0.97) using qemu. However, when I type `kernel 200+9`, I get the message

```
[Multiboot-elf, <0x100000:0x80:0x4008>(bad), entry=0x10000c]
```

This is what I expect except for the (bad) part. If I type `boot` now GRUB just hangs.

I think the numbers 0x100000, 0x44, 0x4008 stand for the .text segment start address, the .bss start address, and the .bss section size, respectively. I think this because running `objdump -h` on the kernel image gives this output:

```
kernel.bin:     file format elf32-i386

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
  0 .text         00000044  00100000  00100000  00001000  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  1 .bss          00004008  00100044  00100044  00001044  2**2
                  ALLOC
```

So you can see that the numbers I mentioned almost match up. The issue is that instead of 100044, the start of .bss is just 44. And I think this is the reason why GRUB is saying bad. I can't have a section below 1 MB in memory (low memory). But objdump is telling me my sections are above that threshold, so I don't know what's wrong. Anyway, I'll paste my code below, it's relatively short. Although my question is probably very basic if you've done OS dev before, so the code might be extraneous.

```
;loader.s - contains the multiboot header for grub and calls the main kernel method

global loader                           ; making entry point visible to linker
global magic                            ; we will use this in kmain
global mbd                              ; we will use this in kmain

extern kmain                            ; kmain is defined in kmain.cpp

; setting up the Multiboot header - see GRUB docs for details
MODULEALIGN equ  1<<0                   ; align loaded modules on page boundaries
MEMINFO     equ  1<<1                   ; provide memory map
FLAGS       equ  0x03;MODULEALIGN | MEMINFO  ; this is the Multiboot 'flag' field
MAGIC       equ  0x1BADB002             ; 'magic number' lets bootloader find the header
CHECKSUM    equ -(MAGIC + FLAGS)        ; checksum required

section .text

loader:

align 4
    dd MAGIC
    dd FLAGS
    dd CHECKSUM

; reserve initial kernel stack space
STACKSIZE equ 0x4000                    ; that's 16k.

    mov  esp, stack + STACKSIZE         ; set up the stack
    mov  [magic], eax                   ; Multiboot magic number
    mov  [mbd], ebx                     ; Multiboot info structure

    call kmain                          ; call kernel proper

    cli
.hang:
    hlt                                 ; halt machine should kernel return
    jmp  .hang

section .bss

align 4
stack: resb STACKSIZE                   ; reserve 16k stack on a doubleword boundary
magic: resd 1
mbd:   resd 1
```

.

```
// kernel.c - Contains the main kernel method

void kmain() {
  extern unsigned int magic;

  if (magic != 0x2BADB002) {
    // Something went wrong
  }

  volatile unsigned char *videoram = (unsigned char *) 0xB800;
  videoram[0] = 65;
  videoram[1] = 0x07;
}
```

Below is my custom linker script:

```
ENTRY (loader)

SECTIONS {
    . = 0x00100000;

    .text ALIGN (0x1000) : {
        *(.text)
    }

    .rodata ALIGN (0x1000) :
    {
        *(.rodata*)
    }

    .data ALIGN (0x1000) :
    {
        *(.data)
    }

    .bss :
    {
        sbss = .;
        *(COMMON)
        *(.bss)
        ebss = .;
    }

    /DISCARD/ : {
        *(.eh_frame)
        *(.comment)
    }
}
```

And finally, I build the kernel with the following lines:

```
nasm -f elf -o loader.o loader.s
gcc -c -o kernel.o kernel.c
ld -T linker.ld -o kernel.bin loader.o kernel.o
cat stage1 stage2 pad kernel.bin > floppy.img
```

Where stage1 and stage2 are file from GRUB Legacy and pad is any 750 byte file (So stage1+stage2+pad have a file size of 102400 bytes, or 200 blocks, which is why I boot with kernel 200+9).

Finally, I run the kernel in qemu:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -fda floppy.img
```

Comment: Repository with that example working: https://github.com/cirosantilli/x86-bare-metal-examples/tree/d217b180be4220a0b4a453f31275d38e697a99e0/multiboot/osdev

Answer (score 24, accepted):

+1 for nice question with all the details, thank you.

At least on my machine the generated `kernel.bin` comes out as 4869 bytes, which only fits in 10 sectors not 9. Also, the VGA text memory is at `0xb8000` not `0xb800` (one more zero - `0xb800` is the real mode segment, has to be multiplied by 16). With those little adjustments it works fine here.

Comment: Wow, the issue was with 0xb800... I thought it was hanging but it really just wasn't putting the character in the right spot in memory... Although I'm still confused about what this meant then: `<0x100000:0x80:0x4008>(bad)`, since you shouldn't be allowed to have a segment in low memory (if I interpreted the meaning of the numbers correctly)...

Comment: And to clarify for others a bit, it still boots even though it says (bad).

Comment: It says `(bad)` if you don't load enough sectors. It may still work if nothing important resides in that part. Have you tried with `200+10`?

Comment: Oh, you're right! I was rounding down when I obviously should have been rounding up. Thanks!